# React Native Click events inside Android Native WebView not working

Tags: react-native

I am using Android native WebView and iOS web-kit as part of the native module and wrapped inside GestureHandlerRoot.
Click events in Android are not working whereas for iOS, they are working fine.
current lib version react-native-gesture-handler": "2.9.0
tried with upgrading to 2.13 but it still same issue.

```
<GestureHandlerRootView style={styles.gestureHandlerStyles}>
<Root initialProps={props} />
</GestureHandlerRootView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GestureHandler touch events can propagated with the webView behaviour, based on your use case those are a possible solutions:

1- Enable JS in WebView (**javaScriptEnabled={true}**):

```
<WebView
  source={{ uri: 'YOUR_WEBSITE' }}
  javaScriptEnabled={true}
/>
```

2- for debugiging purpose add the following callback:

```
<WebView
          source={{ uri: 'YOUR_WEBSITE' }}
        onMessage={event => {
            const data = event.nativeEvent.data;
            console.log("onMessage: ", data);
          }}
    />
```

could you please try those two approaches and give me your feedback in case the provided solutions didn’t work.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.
JS is already enabled, not working.